# mysql query for selecting based on diverging conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with the following columnns

```
id status created_at
1   close  ..
2   close  ..
3   open   ..
```

Now, i am trying to fetch all records that are newer than 3 months like this

```
select * from table where created_at >= NOW() - interval 3 month
```

But i also want records that are open and older than 3 months, how to add that condition in the same sql?

Comment: Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Please go through this link once: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Answer (score 1):

Just add that condition to your `where` clause. Note that you don't need to include the "older than 3 months" part to the condition as anything newer than 3 months is picked up by the first part of the `where` clause anyway so the `OR status = 'open'` will only find additional records older than 3 months.

```
select * 
from table
where columnX = 'some ID' AND
   (created_at >= NOW() - interval 3 month OR status = 'open')
```

Comment: Hi sorry, my bad i didnt ask the full question, the challenge here was i have multiple necessary where conditions before this date comparison too, like columnnX= some id and these 2 conditions, how to use them in unison?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using OR

```
select * from table where created_at >= NOW() - interval 3 month 
or (status='open' and created_at < NOW() - interval 3 month)
```

Answer (score 0):

use OR

```
select * from table where created_at >= NOW() - interval 3 month or status='open'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from Table where add_date(date_column, interval 3 month)> now() or status = "open";
```